# handling data between two views in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have two views and I use routes to access them. My main view is a list that uses `ListController`.

That controller does an `$http` request and gets some data back and on `success` I do: `$scope.data = response.data;`

When I click on a list item, my route goes to `#/view/:id`

I am able to get the `id` using `routeParams` in my other controller: `DetailController`

Since `$scope.data` was part of the `ListController`, how do I access say `$scope.data` in my `DetailController`?

(or at least pass `$scope.data[some Id]` to `DetailController`)

**EDIT**

```
app.factory('dataService', function(data)
{
  var data = data;
  return data;
});
```

the answer was to place this in my `DetailController`. `response.data` was still available to me

```
presentationService().then(
    function success(response)
    {
        log(response.data);
    },
    function error(response)
    {
        log(response);
    }
);
```

Comment: `dataService` should be making the $http request

Comment: @charlietfl see my last comment on InviS' post

Comment: here's another way that doesn't require using `then` in controller http://plunker.co/edit/o0opykZ7QOPfxGZCRNFp?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl I like this method more than what I came up with. Since I am using ng-repeat on the $scope.presentations variable, the list isn't being populated. How can I tell when the request is finished from within the list controller?

Comment: shouldn't have to check if it's finished or not, listeners on scope object will modify DOM when data changes. Loop of pushing response into empty array is what's currently changing the data. Am trying to figure out another approach to updating data in service from $http using promises. Haven't got that solution figured out yet

Comment: yeah I thought the same too. It should update the DOM when its loded, but it isn't. I am trying to do a $broadcast event right now and I am successfully listening for it, however, still not updating the dom. I tried `$scope.$apply()` but it says digest already in progress

Comment: same demo but with 3 second delay updating the data from response. Only modification made is `$timeout` within `$http success  `. `ng-repeat` automatically updates still . http://plunker.co/edit/tsD4e5YQd9rrTBQOzRfn?p=preview

Comment: that would only happen if data was received within 3 seconds though

Comment: no...success callback doesn't fire until data is received. I added extra 3 seconds after it is received and `ng-repeat` works fine

Comment: Oh, you are correct. Mine still isn't showing though. I think I know why. My div where the list populates has a `ng-show="presentations"` I removed that and the list populates now. I need to see how I can still utilize `ng-show`

Comment: try `presentations.length`

Comment: success! that worked perfectly. This method turned out a lot cleaner and even got rid of some unnecessary variables. Turns out, I didn't need the timeout even. If you post your answer below, I will accept yours.

Comment: timeout was there just to show you that even with a long delay auto update occurs

Comment: indeed, but in the end it wasn't needed. It was the `ng-show="presentations"` making the list now show. `presentations.length` did the trick though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use scopes for sharing data between controllers. Use service instead.
Watch this short movie: http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers/

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok I am trying to get this to work. In my http success function, I am doing `function success(response) { dataService(response.data) }` and I am getting `dataService` is undefined.` I'll post my factory in my question. I think I am doing it wrong. Also, I am passing `dataService` to my `ListController`

Comment: Move your $http tasks into service. And you will be able to cache data inside the service. And data will be able for sharing.

Comment: My http request is already a service. Let's make this easier...here is a pastie: http://pastie.org/7273427

Comment: Service that makes $http request should also share data between controllers.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I cannot get it to work. I am watching another youtube video on how this works

Comment: How do I set a variable equal to the data returned in my `presentationService`? As I understand, promise doesn't contain the data returned